# How to set InternetExplorerDriver download directory?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We use Selenium to test file downloads from our web application. Currently we are using Firefox, set it to the desired download directory and make sure no dialogs pop up and no user interaction is required when downloading files.

For the FirefoxDriver we do this:

```
File downloadDir = ...;
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir.getAbsolutePath());
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "...");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

What to do for InternetExplorerDriver to achieve the same effect? I couldn't find a InternetExplorerProfile nor a switch in DesiredCapabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("???", "???");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 8):

Internet Explorer doesn't use profiles. It's a limitation of the browser itself, not the IE driver. As such, there is no way to automatically download files to a specified location with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Hi Jim, do you know if the new Edge browser use Profiles? Specifying download location is a critical requirement for our tests. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no difference between Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer with respect to using "profiles." The profile is still tied to the logged-in user account in Windows.