# Selenium: How to save a file downloaded, in a specific folder?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver

I am automating a scenario using Selenium webdriver. When I click on the button using the selenium java script in IE, it downloads an excel file. However I need to click on the "Save As" option in that bar, and then provide a name to it, in the Save As pop-up, and save it in a specific directory.

I doubt if Selenium alone could do this.
Could anyone pls guide me in achieving this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default download directory with IE (Internet Explorer 11)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241157/how-to-change-the-default-download-directory-with-ie-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Any help on this pls?